# How can I respond with JSON to some http GET requests and HTML to others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am creating a game in Java, and I need my Java clients to retrieve information from my Ruby on Rails web application in JSON format.

How do I convince my application to respond sometimes with JSON and sometimes with HTML, depending on the nature of the request?

This will always redirect to the homepage, and it seems the JSON part never even runs.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    redirect_to :root
  end
  format.json do
    render :json => {"test" => "test"}.to_json
  end
end
```

Here is an example of my request:

```
PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

request.print(  "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + 
                               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
                               "Authorization: Basic " + encodedAuth + "\r\n" +
                               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

If this cannot (or should not) be done, would it be reasonable for me to create an "API" section of my website that always renders JSON?

Comment: Paste the result from routes.rb affectin the resource. Also paste a request of example. To see if the request is made with the correct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not requesting json data from  your java app. So by default its rendering html.
I believe you should do something like this in your java app

```
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

Which will make sure you want response in `json` format.

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. I am using raw HTTP requests, though, and I need to use the apache client to access this method. Do you know how I might set a header using PrintWriter? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: I'm sorry, the kind of extensive java knowledge I have really really limits me from answering your question. :P Hope you find out how to fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

> This will always redirect to the homepage, and it seems the JSON part
>   never even runs.

If this never runs might be because you are not sending the proper request headers in the java game. Try to get the router in the browser with `'.json'` at the end of the url and you will be able to retrieve the json response.